# multiplication of probabilities of independent events with confidence intervals in archaeology

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, social-science

I am an archaeologist and I am devising rules for attributing objects to a certain region based a combination of region-specific traits. Particularly I would like to estimate probability that objects displaying a combination of two traits originate from the certain region. I consider (arbitrarily, I admit) the traits I observe to occur independently and I establish their occurrence rates from the limited number of securely attributable objects, presently known (hence, I cannot just increase the sample size). Say, there are 34 objects of known origin displaying trait A and 29 of these are from region X. And there are 84 objects of known origin displaying trait B and 75 of these are from region X. It should be noted that very few objects appear in both samples (i. e., traits A and B but rarely co-occur, whence my arbitrary judgement on their independence). Using the Wilson's test with Yates' continuity correction (the prop.test function in R) I estimate that the probability that trait A occurs outside region X is between 0.06 and 0.32, and the probability that trait B occurs outside region X is between 0.05 and 0.20 at 95% confidence level.

```
prop.test(34-29, 34, conf.level = 0.95, correct=TRUE) # for trait A
prop.test(84-75, 84, conf.level = 0.95, correct=TRUE) # for trait B
```

Now I want to calculate the probability that a combination of traits A and B occurs outside region X. Would it be correct to say that it may be defined by the products of the lower and upper confidence limits of the independent traits? Would it be correct to say that P(A ∩ B) lies within the confidence limits 0.06*0.05=0.00 and 0.32*0.20=0.06 and that thus an object displaying both traits A and B stems from region X with probability P(A ∩ B) > 1-0.06=94% at 95% confidence level (with the assumption that the two traits are distributed independently)? Or do I miss something? Does the confidence level change when I multiply the probabilities?

UPDATE
In a comment below it is suggested that I'd better apply another method instead. However, I reckon that if there is no mistake in my calculations, they could explain in very simple terms why the combination of two traits on a single monument provides sufficient evidence and occurrence of only one trait does not.

UPDATE 2:
From what I observe applying the method suggested by @jwimberley to my data, the confidence limits of the product seem be narrower than the products of the original lower and upper confidence limits. Would it be safe to say that this should always be the case? (Or in other words that the confidence level corresponding to the product of the original confidence limits would be => 95%)?

Comment: I bet you would be happier with a comprehensive, multivariate model to predict region.  This would potentially save you work, especially if you add variables, and concisely account for major dependencies that exist between predictors.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed, I could as well use a binomial generalized linear model and get prediction probabilities and standard errors for all possible combinations of traits. However, I wonder if there is an answer to my question.

Comment: For basically I need to explain in very simple terms how my method works and why the combination of two traits on a single monument provides sufficient evidence and occurrence of only one trait does not.

Comment: Have you verified that these traits are indeed independent?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765887/confidence-interval-multiplication Although the answer there perhaps does not completely address this question

Comment: I understand that what I need to check in this case is whether the traits A and B are independent among the objects from outside region X, because I estimate the probability of their co-occurrence on an object  from outside region X. In this context the traits are independent (as per chi-square test of independence). In the whole population including object from region X and objects of unknown origin the traits are not independent, not least because they both predict that an object comes from region X.

Comment: @jwimberley thanks for the answer; was something wrong with it that you removed it?

Comment: @greenb Yes, I think I have a big mistake in it, confusing probability densities with probabilities, and also confusing probabilities with probabilities *of* probabilities. Situations like this can be a little bit confusing when you have two levels of probabilities. Later I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Another note: it seems you are reasoning with things like the "probability of being from X given trait A," "probability of having trait A given being from X," etc. I don't fully understand your details, but you should make sure you are applying Bayes' rule in your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside some of the questions addressed in the comments (is there a better procedure? have you verified that the traits are indeed independent), here is a direct answer: No, the confidence interval of the product is not equal to the product of the separate confidence intervals. The first confidence interval essentially states that
$$
\int_{p_A^L}^{p_A^U} f_A(p_A) \, dp_A = 0.95
$$
and the second that
$$
\int_{p_B^L}^{p_B^U} f_B(p_B) \, dp_B = 0.95
$$
Note that these are integrals of probability densities of probabilities!. Now, what's the density of the product probability $\rho = p_A p_B$? From a [standard result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution), this is
$$
f_{P}(\rho) = \int_0^1 \frac{f_A(p) f_B(\rho/p)}{p} \, dp
$$
The CDF of this distribution is
$$
F_{P}(\rho) = \int_0^1 \frac{f_A(p)}{p} \left( \int_0^\rho  f_B(p'/p) \, dp' \right)\, dp \\
= \int_0^1 f_A(p) F_B(\rho/p) \, dp
$$
It does not follow that
$$
\int_{p_A^L p_B^L}^{p_B^U p_B^U} f_P(\rho) \, d\rho = 0.95
$$
which is what you estimate. What you must solve is
$$
\int_{p_P^L}^{p_P^U} f_P(\rho) \, d\rho = 0.95
$$
for the new confidence interval bounds $p_P^L$ and $p_P^U$

I'm not sure if there is a model-independent way of estimating this.
Here's one idea: some probability confidence intervals are based on methods modeling the densities $f_A$ and $f_B$ as normal distributions or beta distributions. I understand (I believe) that Wilson's test is based on a frequentist method with a normal approximation; an alternative is a Bayesian method using Beta distributions. If you obtain the parameters of these normal distributions or beta distributions, you can analytically (unlikely) or numerically (more likely) compute the above integrals and find your confidence interval.

For example, the `binom` package in R performs Bayesian estimation of binomial proportions with `binom.bayes`.

```
> print(A <- binom.bayes(34-29, 34, conf.level = 0.95))
  method x  n shape1 shape2      mean      lower     upper  sig
1  bayes 5 34    5.5   29.5 0.1571429 0.04866337 0.2771654 0.05
> print(B <- binom.bayes(84-75, 84, conf.level = 0.95))
  method x  n shape1 shape2      mean      lower     upper  sig
1  bayes 9 84    9.5   75.5 0.1117647 0.04949479 0.1793428 0.05
```

We care most about the shape parameters; with these we have $f_A$ and $f_B$ and can numerically compute $f_P$. This is easiest via MC integration:

```
dbetaprod <- Vectorize(function(x,alpha1,beta1,alpha2,beta2) {
    p <- rbeta(1000,alpha1,beta1)
    mean(dbeta(x/p,alpha2,beta2)/p)
},"x")

pbetaprod <- Vectorize(function(x,alpha1,beta1,alpha2,beta2) {
    p <- rbeta(1000,alpha1,beta1)
    mean(pbeta(x/p,alpha2,beta2))
},"x")
```

You can then plot the density and CDF to find the confidence interval:

[image]

[image]

It looks like the 95% confidence window upper bound is about 0.04 (4%). You can modify this procedure to suit your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your extensive answer. From what I observe applying the method you suggested to my data, the confidence limits of the product seem be narrower than the products of the original lower and upper confidence limits. Would it be safe to say that this should always be the case? (Or in other words that the confidence level corresponding to the product of the original confidence limits would be => 95%)?

Comment: I don't think it would be safe to say this, no.